# Air resistance in two dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

Suppose I have a ball moving through the air parallel to the ground, and diagonally in some 2D $x$ , $y$ coordinates (along the line $y=x$). Let's say its velocity is 1 units, which means on the $x$ axis and on the $y$ axis separately it's $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Modeling air resistance as approximately $F=Kv^{2}$, say with $K=1$, I could say that along the $x$ axis, the resistance $F_{x}$ is $K\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}^{2}$ = 1, and similarly $F_y=1$, so the total air resistance, acting diagonally, is $F=\sqrt{2}$.

On the other hand, if I redraw coordinate axes so that one of them coincides with the velocity vector, along that axis $v=1$ , $F=Kv^{2}=1$.

Where did I go wrong? Is it impermissible to consider air resistance acting separately in each dimension, and why?

Comment: only linear air resistance behaves in the way you're proposing.

Comment: how did you get  $K(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2 = 1$ ? shouldnt it be $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

As a vector, if you want the air resistance force to (a) have a magnitude proportional to the square of the speed and (b) directed opposite the velocity vector, then the correct formula would be
$$
\vec{F} = - K |\vec{v}| \vec{v}.
$$
It is not too hard to see that this satisfies the criteria above.  But note that in terms of components, this means that
\begin{align*}
F_x &= - K ( v_x^2 + v_y^2)^{1/2} v_x  \neq - K v_x^2, \text{ and} \\ 
F_y &= - K ( v_x^2 + v_y^2)^{1/2} v_y \neq - K v_y^2. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand now. My confusion originally stemmed from a fascinating problem where air resistance acts in two dimensions (the problem: A football at distance L from a gate is kicked straight at it with speed v>0, and due to a sidewise perpendicular wind of speed u>0 arrives at the gateline at distance h from the gate; find the time of travel to the gateline). It's natural to consider velocities and resistance forces separately in x and y, but beyond being difficult to solve with quadratic force, I now realize it's incorrect b/c the force acts along the total velocity vector.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying your linear thinking to a nonlinear situation.

If a number is split into pieces, you can add up the pieces to recover the original number. If the number is raised to a power other than 1.0, that is no longer possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your math is incorrect.

You say for $K=1$

$$F_x= K \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 = 1$$

The correct expression is:

$$F_x= K \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 = (1)*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Same for $F_y$.  So the resultant drag force is:

$$\sqrt{F_x^2+F_y^2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} = \sqrt {\frac 1 2} $$

As a tip, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \sqrt{\frac1 2 }   \; \; $ and sometimes it is more instructive to write it that way.

Comment: My math is wrong (thanks), but so is yours, I think. F_x=F_y=1/2, as you say, but then the resultant force is $\sqrt(F_x^2+F_y^2) = \sqrt(1/4 + 1/4) = \sqrt(2)/2.$